# Tabulator's output of print function does not include table footer column calculation and text alignments

Tags: tabulator

I am using Tabulator version 4.3 and trying to print a table (which has `columnCalcs: both`) using print function. I have set `printCopyStyle:true`, but the output of print does not include footer row (column calculation at the bottom of the table); also alignment of numbers which is set to right does not appear right aligned. The footer and alignment both appear correctly in the Tabulator table, but not in print copy.

Please check [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wmbhtzag/1/).

Are these features not available or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are missing the working demo of your code

Comment: @dota2pro thanks for your feedback, added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tabledata = [{
    dep: "A",
    name: "Oli Bob",
    score: 100
  },
  {
    dep: "A",
    name: "Jamie Newhart",
    score: 120
  },
  {
    dep: "D",
    name: "Gemma Jane",
    score: 90
  },
  {
    dep: "D",
    name: "James Newman",
    score: 100
  },
];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: "250px",
  data: tabledata,
  groupBy: "dep",
  columnCalcs: "both",
  printAsHtml: true,
  printCopyStyle: true,
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      title: "Score",
      field: "score",
      align: "right",
      bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
  ],
});
```

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="report-print" onclick="table.print();">Print </button>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
```